# Django RawQuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm try to do a RawQuerySet in my django model, but it not return any data. I do this query direct at database and works well, but to django RawQuerySet nothing is returned.

Could you help me?

```
data_in = "'2022-05-15'"
data_out = "'2022-08-20'"
id_estudo = 1

query = f'''SELECT ag.id, dia, first_name, last_name, descricao, modelo, serialNumber, acronimo 
        FROM model_1 ag,model_2 ma, model_3 user, model_4 es
        ON ag.model_2_id = ma.id AND ag.model_3_id = user.id AND ag.model_4_id = es.id 
        WHERE dia BETWEEN {data_in} and {data_out} AND es.id = {ester_id};
        '''


return Model.objects.raw(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use f string format to perform rawquery, it is vulnerable to sql injection

do this instead,

```
>>> lname = 'Doe'
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
```

Also if you need mapping to column name,

```
>>> name_map = {'first': 'first_name', 'last': 'last_name', 'bd': 'birth_date', 'pk': 'id'}
>>> Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM some_other_table', translations=name_map)
```

Django Documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/